# How to change a logo on a wordpress site that is part of a 7 site multisite?

Tags: multisite, logo

We have a multisite which has 7 sites attached to the network.

We have recently had some branding changes and are now in the process of revising the look and feel of one of our sites to represent the new branding. I'm trying to add the new logo to one of the microsites but realised its not as simple as adding a logo to a single wordpress site as the 'add logo' button is not there when going through to customising the theme then changing the logo through the 'site identity' section.

Would someone be able to help me on how I can change the header logo for one of the sites.

The site we would like to make the changes to is built using the 'bridge child' theme.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Regards,
Monish

Comment: Does theme implement native Theme Logo feature at all? It’s not clear from the question if it's implemented and _missing_ or just not present in theme.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Trick to change the logo

Go to Site3 (site you want to change the logo) dashboard / Customize / Additional CSS place below code and and put your logo under `wp-content/themes/bridge/img/`

Here I installed bridge on local host and created 2 sites on network .

```
.q_logo a img{
background-image: url(wp-content/themes/bridge/img/pin.png)!important;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:70px !important;
width:90px !important;
object-position: -99999px 99999px;
}
```

I used pin.png image to display instead of logo, give width and height as per your logo size.

hope this trick can solve your problem

Comment: I hope this trick worked for you ?